# Magento - Different amount of stock/availability on different DATES

Tags: stock

The only thing holding me back from moving from woo to magento is because I sell tour packages with varying amount of seats/"stocks" on different days.

Magento does not offer an extension nor solution that helps me not only sell, but manage these stocks/dates.

Is there a solution / work around ?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly NOT handled out of the box.
1) The easiest solution is to have the same product but with different dates as custom options.

2) Harder and more to manage would be different products for each date, much greater control over stock/quantity per date.

3) Hardest solution is to create a custom product and setup your own rules.

I have done all, and 2) seems to be the best option.  You could also try to use Categories as your main page, with individual products as the dates.  Its a spin off of Configurable products.  The difference is in configurable, you have a main ( parent product ), then the configurable options like size and color are child products.

Using a category as the description for the Band, then the dates as products may get you to a workable solution pretty quick with no real customization needed, except perhaps to the layout of the category page to show the information properly.  Here is a screen shot of what we did.
This is a category page, with the dates as virtual products
[image]